# Why does limit_except GET { deny all; } not work for PURGE requests when using nginx_http_mirror_module?

Tags: nginx, varnish

I am trying to mirror all `GET` requests on my nginx server, to another web application for split testing. This works and filters all request types but GET - but - unfortunately it also sends `PURGE` requests onwards to the mirror. So somehow the the `limit_except` seems to not filter those `PURGE` request.

Why would that be?

**Here are parts of my configuration:**

From HTTP block:

```
split_clients "${remote_addr}AAA" $mirror_backend {
    30% web_mirror;
    *   "";
 }
```

From server block:

```
location / {
    
    gunzip on;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    mirror /mirror;

    proxy_pass http://varnish;
  }

location = /mirror {
  internal;
    limit_except GET {
    deny  all;
  }
  if ($mirror_backend = "") {
    return 400;
  }
  
  include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
  proxy_pass http://$mirror_backend$request_uri;
}
```

Example output from the mirrored server which receives PURGE requests - which it shouldn't:

```
10.0.0.10 mydomain.com 2023-10-25T14:51:52+02:00 "PURGE /path/here HTTP/1.1" 405 0 "-" "cache-warmer/android" - "-" - - - - 99cae641-0961-48b3-9965-bfd4a8ed3ff7 0.091 - - - - ruby
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#limit_except),

> The method parameter can be one of the following: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, MKCOL, COPY, MOVE, OPTIONS, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, LOCK, UNLOCK, or PATCH.

As you can see, `PURGE` is not recognized by `limit_except`. A workaround is to deny it explicitly ([like they do here](https://serverfault.com/a/382480)), like so

```
location = /mirror {

    internal;

    if ($request_method = PURGE) {
        return 444;
    }

    limit_except GET {
        deny all;
    }

    if ($mirror_backend = "") {
        return 400;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://$mirror_backend$request_uri;
}
```

I've used 444 but feel free to use something else you deem more appropriate.

Comment: Hmm I would say it's a "bug" in the implementation, that you the directive says "only GET and deny all other" but then it actually let's requests through, if they are using a method which happens to not be in a specific list. Wouldn't you say so?

Comment: @NielsKristian it does exactly what it claims, but I agree it should provide a way to handle unrecognized methods like `PURGE`.